# Segmentation Fault searching for End of Line

Tags: c++

I'm writing code that counts the amount of lines and characters of a file.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>    
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    ifstream read(argv[1]);


    char line[256];
    int nLines=0, nChars=0, nTotalChars=0;
    read.getline(line, 256);

    while(read.good())                      /
        {
        nChars=0;

        int i=0;
        while(line[i]!='\n')
            {

            if ((int)line[i]>32) {nChars++;}
            i++;
            }

        nLines++;
        nTotalChars= nTotalChars + nChars;
        read.getline(line, 256);
        }
    cout << "The number of lines is "<< nLines << endl;
    cout << "The number of characters is "<< nTotalChars << endl;
    }
```

The line `while(line[i]!='\n')` seems to be the cause of the following error

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I can't figure out what's wrong. The internet tells me that I'm checking for the end of a line correctly as far as I can tell.

Comment: But what if your line was longer than `256` characters (which is currently the maximum size of your character array) ?

Comment: Yeah I realise that that can happen. But it would just mean that I skip a part of the text in my file right?

Comment: @Nbr44 I'm pretty sure that's taken care of by `read.getline(line, 256);`, which limits the number of characters written (_including_ terminating null) to 256. The number of lines will be off, but that shouldn't be causing the error.

Comment: Consider the [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) version of [`getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: @JAB the while loop doesn't check for terminating null.

Comment: @Nbr44 Oh, I suppose that would cause the error as the loop would keep iterating past the end of the array. Well then.

Comment: @JAB The number of lines _and_ the number of characters may be off.  (Think of a line which contained a '\0', for example.  Or what happens if the last line of the file doesn't contain a `'\n'`.)  Using `std::istream::getline` is very tricky, and should be avoided at all costs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code will not find `'\n'` because it is discarded from the input sequence. From the documentation of `getline`:

> The delimiting character is the newline character [...]: when found in the input sequence, it is extracted from the input sequence, but discarded and not written to s.

You should be searching for `'\0'`:

```
    while(line[i])
        {
        if ((int)line[i]>32) {nChars++;}
        i++;
        }
```

Comment: Of course, his code still won't work when he fixes that.  It won't crash, but it will give wrong results.  (And `line[i]` is _not_ a `bool`; it's very bad programming style, and confusing to the reader, to use it as one.  You might try `while ( line[i] != '\0' )`, so the reader knows what the condition you're testing is.)

Comment: @JamesKanze "[implicit checking for zero is] very bad programming style, and confusing to the reader" The construct is idiomatic to C/C++ and it is featured prominently in many popular textbooks, starting with the K&R. Although the decision to use or not to use this idiom is up to the practitioner's choice, I think it is a good idea to learn it early. I wasn't using this idiom for a long time, but then I convinced myself that there's no reason to fight it, given that pretty much every C/C++ programmer understands it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I've use C and C++ for over 25 years, and it still confuses me.  Say what you mean, and mean what you say.  (Most places I've worked have coding guidelines which forbid it, and the original proposal for `bool` in C++ deprecated the conversion.)

Answer (score 1):

Because `getline` will not store `\n`, so the loop:

```
    while(line[i]!='\n')
        {

        if ((int)line[i]>32) {nChars++;}
        i++;
        }
```

will never end, until `line[i]` exceeds the array length and causes segmentation fault.

Comment: "will never end": it ended (with a segmentation fault).  Saying it will never end supposes that the process can access all of it address space, and that there are no zeros in that space.  (He should be glad it crashed.  In a lot of cases, the loop will find a `'\0'` before getting a segment violation; his code would then run, but give very wrong results, which is a much harder error to find.)

Answer (score 1):

You do not have an end of line character in the line.  So, you should be checking for a NULL character (end of string) instead of the end of line.  Also make sure that you do not go past the size of your buffer (256) in your case.

Comment: Just a nit, but there is no such thing as a NULL character.  NULL is (logically, not factually) a pointer.  What he should be checking for is the nul character, usually written `'\0'` in C++.

Answer (score 0):

I think a for loop would be safer:

```
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++ ) {
  //whatever
}
```

Comment: Except that he's using `char line[256];`, and C style arrays don't have a member function `size`.  (Of course, that's the real error: using a C style array rather than `std::string`.)

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code, but for starters, you
shouldn't be reading lines into a `char[]`.  If you use
`std::string`, then you don't have to worry about reading
partial lines, etc.

Then there's the fact that `getline` extracts the `'\n'` from
the file, but does *not* store it, so your code (even modified
to use `std::string`) will never see a `'\n'` in the buffer.  If
you're using string, you iterate from `line.begin()` to
`line.end()`; if you're using a `char[]`, you iterate over the
number of bytes returned by `read.gcount()`, called after the
call to `getline`.  (It's very difficult to get this code right
using a `char[]` *unless* you assume that no text file in the
world contains a `'\0'`.)

Finally, if the last line doesn't end with a `'\n'` (a frequence
case under Windows), you won't process it.  If you're using
`std::string`, you can simply write:

```
std::getline( read, line );
while ( read ) {
    //  ...
    std::getline( read, line );
}
```

or even:

```
while ( std::getline( read, line ) ) {
    ++ nLines;
    for ( std::string::const_iterator current = line.begin();
            current != line.end();
            ++ current ) {
        //  process character *current in line...
    }
}
```

(The latter is ubiquitous, even if it is ugly.)

With `char[]`, you have to replace this with:

```
while ( read.getline( buffer, sizeof(buffer) ) || read.gcount() != 0 ) {
    int l = read.gcount();
    if ( read ) {
        ++ nLines;
    } else {
        if ( read.eof() ) {
            ++ nLines;  //  Last line did not end with a '\n'
        } else {
            read.clear();   //  Line longer than buffer...
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i != l; ++ i ) {
        //  process character buffer[i] in line...
    }
}
```

One final question: what is `(int)line[i] > 32` supposed to
mean?  Did you want `!isspace( line[i] ) &&
!iscntrl( line[i] )`?  (That's not at all what it does, of
course.)